# string as a argument in a function in c

Tags: c, string, function

I'm making a function for retrieving a integer from a text file, according with its line and field number.

The code is shown below, the main issue is that I'm having problems with the functions arguments.

I'm having an error flag at the `return value;` it says: that `value` is undeclare

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* define function */
int getlinefieldint(const char FILENAME[], int TARGETLINE, int TARGETFIELD, int LINESIZE);

int main ()
{
    static const char FILENAMEint[] = "resultdata1M";
    int linea=1000;
    int campo=2;
    int tamanolinea=128;
    int value;
    value=getlinefieldint(FILENAMEint,linea,campo,tamanolinea);
    printf("%d",value);

    return 0;
}

/* declare function */
int getlinefieldint(const char FILENAME[], int TARGETLINE, int TARGETFIELD, int LINESIZE)
{
    FILE *ARCHIVO;
    ARCHIVO = fopen ( FILENAME, "r" );       
    int C,QUERY_GENE_NUM;
    unsigned int NEWLINE_COUNT = 0;
    while ( (C=fgetc(ARCHIVO)) != EOF )
    {
        if ( C == '\n' )
        {
        NEWLINE_COUNT++;
        }
    }
    printf("La cantidad de genes a evaluar es: %d\n",QUERY_GENE_NUM);
    rewind(ARCHIVO);

    if (TARGETLINE <= NEWLINE_COUNT)
    {
        int j,value;
        int stoplimitline;
        char LINE[LINESIZE];
        char *BUFFER;
        char *TOKEN_SEPARA;
        char *RETURNPTR;
        BUFFER=(char *)malloc(24 * sizeof(char));
        RETURNPTR=(char *)malloc(24 * sizeof(char));
        while (stoplimitline < TARGETLINE)
        {
            fgets(LINE, sizeof LINE, ARCHIVO);
            puts(LINE);
        }
        TOKEN_SEPARA = strtok(LINE, " ");
        for (j=1;j<=TARGETFIELD;j++)
            {
                if(j!= TARGETFIELD)
                {
                    BUFFER=strcpy(RETURNPTR,TOKEN_SEPARA);
                    puts(BUFFER);
                    TOKEN_SEPARA = strtok(NULL, " ");   /* hacer que brinque el puntero al siguiente patron */
                }
                else
                {
                    value=atoi(BUFFER);
                }
            }


    }

    return value ;
}
```

Comment: That's because it's declared inside a block, and thus has limited scope, rather than at the start of the function code. It is therefore unreachable by the `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if (TARGETLINE <= NEWLINE_COUNT)
{
    int j, value;
    // ...
}
return value;
```

Note that in C (and many other languages), variables only "exist" in the code block they are declared in. So if you declare a variable inside a code block (such as an `if`, `while` or `for` code block), then the variable will simply not exist when the program leaves this block of code.

The simple solution here is then to declare `int value` *before* you enter the `if` block:

```
int value;
if (TARGETLINE <= NEWLINE_COUNT)
{
    int j;
    // ...
}
return value;
```

Answer (score 3):

`value` will cease to exist once

```
if (TARGETLINE <= NEWLINE_COUNT)
```

goes out of scope, because `value`'s declaration is within the `if` statement.

The `return` statement is outside of the `if` statement, which means that `value` will be attempted to be returned even though it does not exist.

Comment: Okay, my answer covers the same information as the other answers, and it also came first. What is so bad about it that it deserves a downvote, then?

Comment: It's not really correct. Variables in C are lexically scoped, so even if you enter an if statement, any variables declared inside the if block will go out of scope (and hence stop existing) as soon as you leave the block and move on. A variable will never exist outside of the code block it was declared in.

Comment: @Frxstrem Ok, I fixed the issues. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

Put the declaration of `value` outside of `if` block.

```
/* declare function */
int getlinefieldint(const char FILENAME[], int TARGETLINE, int TARGETFIELD, int LINESIZE)
{
    FILE *ARCHIVO;
    int value = 0; //or whatever default value it should have
```